# Using fastai (pytorch) in c# code, how to normalize Bitmap with mean and std?

Tags: c#, machine-learning, pytorch, ml.net, fast-ai

A few days ago i switched from tensorflow to fastai for my c# Project. But now i am facing a problem with my normalisation. For both i use an onnx pipeline to load the model and the data.

```
var onnxPipeline = mLContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(resizing: ImageResizingEstimator.ResizingKind.Fill, outputColumnName: inputName,
                                                                 imageWidth: ImageSettings.imageWidth, imageHeight: ImageSettings.imageHeight,
                                                                 inputColumnName: nameof(ImageInputData.Image)) 
                .Append(mLContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: inputName, interleavePixelColors: true, scaleImage: 1 / 255f))
                .Append(mLContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(outputColumnName: outputName, inputColumnName: inputName, modelFile: onnxModelPath));

var emptyData = mLContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(new List<ImageInputData>());
var onnxModel = onnxPipeline.Fit(emptyData);
```

with

```
    class ImageInputData
    {
        [ImageType(ImageSettings.imageHeight, ImageSettings.imageWidth)]
        public Bitmap Image { get; set; }

        public ImageInputData(byte[] image)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(image))
            {
                Image = new Bitmap(ms);
            }
        }
        public ImageInputData(Bitmap image)
        {
            Image = image;
        }
    }
```

After using fastai i learned, that the models get better accuracy if the data is normalized with a specific mean and standard deviation (because i used the resnet34 model it should be means { 0.485, 0.456, 0.406 } stds = { 0.229, 0.224, 0.225 } respectively).
So the pixelvalues (for each color ofc.) have to be transformed with those values to match the trainings images. But how can i achive this in C#? 
What i tried so far is:

```
int imageSize = 256;
double[] means = new double[] { 0.485, 0.456, 0.406 }; // used in fastai model
double[] stds = new double[] { 0.229, 0.224, 0.225 };
Bitmap bitmapImage = inputBitmap;
Image image = bitmapImage;

Color[] pixels = new Color[imageSize * imageSize];
for (int x = 0; x < bitmapImage.Width; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < bitmapImage.Height; y++)
   {
      Color pixel = bitmapImage.GetPixel(x, y);
      pixels[x + y] = pixel;
      double red = (pixel.R - (means[0] * 255)) / (stds[0] * 255); // *255 to scale the mean and std values to the Bitmap
      double gre = (pixel.G - (means[1] * 255)) / (stds[1] * 255);
      double blu = (pixel.B - (means[2] * 255)) / (stds[2] * 255);
      Color pixel_n = Color.FromArgb(pixel.A, (int)red, (int)gre, (int)blu);
      bitmapImage.SetPixel(x, y, pixel_n);

   }
}
```

Ofcourse its not working, because the Colorvalues can`t be negative (which i realised only later).
But how can i achive this normalisation between -1 and 1 for my model in C# with the onnx-model?

Is there a different way to feed the model or to handle the normalisation?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to switch from an onnx pipeline to an onnx Inferencesession, which is in my view simpler and better to understand:

```
public List<double> UseOnnxSession(Bitmap image, string onnxModelPath)
{
      double[] means = new double[] { 0.485, 0.456, 0.406 };
      double[] stds = new double[] { 0.229, 0.224, 0.225 };

      using (var session = new InferenceSession(onnxModelPath))
      {
          List<double> scores = new List<double>();
          Tensor<float> t1 = ConvertImageToFloatData(image, means, stds);
          List<float> fl = new List<float>();

          var inputMeta = session.InputMetadata;
          var inputs = new List<NamedOnnxValue>()
          {
             NamedOnnxValue.CreateFromTensor<float>("input_1", t1)
          };
          using (var results = session.Run(inputs))
          {
              foreach (var r in results)
              {
                  var x = r.AsTensor<float>().First();
                  var y = r.AsTensor<float>().Last();
                  var softmaxScore = Softmax(new double[] { x, y });
                  scores.Add(softmaxScore[0]);
                  scores.Add(softmaxScore[1]);
              }
           }
           return scores;
       }
}

// Create your Tensor and add transformations as you need.
public static Tensor<float> ConvertImageToFloatData(Bitmap image, double[] means, double[] std)
{
      Tensor<float> data = new DenseTensor<float>(new[] { 1, 3, image.Width, image.Height });
      for (int x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
      {
           for (int y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
           {
               Color color = image.GetPixel(x, y);
               var red = (color.R - (float)means[0] * 255) / ((float)std[0] * 255);
               var gre = (color.G - (float)means[1] * 255) / ((float)std[1] * 255);
               var blu = (color.B - (float)means[2] * 255) / ((float)std[2] * 255);
               data[0, 0, x, y] = red;
               data[0, 1, x, y] = gre;
               data[0, 2, x, y] = blu;
            }
       }
       return data;
}
```

Also i have to use my own Softmax method on these scores to get the real probabilities out of my model:

```
        public double[] Softmax(double[] values)
        {
            double[] ret = new double[values.Length];
            double maxExp = values.Select(Math.Exp).Sum();
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                ret[i] = Math.Round((Math.Exp(values[i]) / maxExp), 4);
            }
            return ret;
        }
```

Hope this helps someone who has a similar Problem.

Comment: Hey I'm someone and I had a similar problem and you helped. Thanks.